# Unable to catch throw from constructor in generic method

Tags: c#

I'm unable to catch the exception in the following code:

```
internal class Program {
    private class Wat {
        public Wat() {
            throw new Exception("how do i exception");
        }
    }

    private static T BreakIt<T>() where T : new() {
        return new T();
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        try {
            BreakIt<Wat>();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("it broke: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

this doesn't work either:

```
internal class Program {
    private class Wat {
        public Wat() {
            throw new Exception("how do i exception");
        }
    }

    private static T BreakIt<T>() where T : new() {
        try {
            return new T();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("it broke: " + e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        BreakIt<Wat>();
    }
}
```

however it works when the exception isn't thrown from the constructor:

```
internal class Program {
    private class Wat {
        public void Break() {
            throw new Exception("how do i exception");
        }
    }

    private static T BreakIt<T>() where T : Wat, new() {
        T t = new T();
        t.Break();
        return t;
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        try {
            BreakIt<Wat>();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("it broke: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

This happens both in debug and release mode. My game is started using a generic method which does all the setting up and i'm trying to catch all unhandled exceptions for my crash reporter.

Comment: All three of those work (if you replace `return null` with `return default(T)` in the second example). They all print `it broke: ...`. If you are debugging from VS, you may need to put a `Console.ReadKey()` at the end of `Main` so you can see the output.

Comment: Can you please tell us why you think you're unable to catch those exceptions. How are you verifying whether you catch them or not? FYI the code does indeed work (with the exception of `return null;` in the middle example).

Comment: I have some code there which will keep it open, i just left it out because i thought it would be best to give the shortest snippet that reproduces it. For me the exception is [not being caught](http://puu.sh/7mj2a.png), VS2013 and .NET 4.5

Comment: Try running it with CTRL-F5.... visual studio might just be showing you the exception before it gets caught because you are debugging. Ctrl-F5 runs without debugging, so you'll see for sure what's going on.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Sorry my original code had the Wat constraint which made the return null valid

Comment: @JohnGibb in that case it does indeed seem to catch the exception, but it throws a System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException with the message Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Which is not the exception i'm throwing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this happens because it actually creates a different exception in the background, so yours is caught by *framework code* instead and not by your exception handler.

In .NET you can't call methods on generic type parameters directly[1], so a method

```
public static T New<T>() where T : new()
{
  return new T();
}
```

is actually compiled as

```
public static T New<T>() where T : new()
{
    if (default(T) != null)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
    return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
}
```

(in release mode). The `Activate` class apparently uses reflection, which handles the original exception and throws a `TargetInvocationException` instead.

[1] You can compile IL code that does it just fine using ilasm.exe, but .NET and Mono will throw an exception on loading the method or surrounding type, respectively.

Comment: Wow, had no idea that happened. So `new T()` must be significantly more expensive then using the actual constructor directly?

Comment: Thanks, this combined with @JohnGibb's comment about not attaching the debugger made me realize what's going on.

Comment: @JohnGibb Yes, definitely (but it probably has not much significance overall). Not having static calls on generic type parameters is also the main issue with the usual functional languages on .NET. F# works around this with static generics that (afaik) create new copies of a function for each type combination or inline it directly. It avoids the reflection slowdown, but the downside is that it's not possible to bind them at runtime.

Comment: @JohnGibb Something to note though is that this is (afaik) the _only_ unusually expensive call on generics. Virtual calls are instead bound using the type that declares them and polymorphism is restricted to the generic type parameter using [an additional instruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). (This also clones methods for value types transparently at runtime.)

Answer (score 0):

If that is only happening within the game framework, maybe [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/01/11/9946736.aspx) could have something to do with it.

Maybe the framework uses Tasks to distribute the work. Can you resume the execution after the debugger halts?

Comment: The framework is my own and it does not use tasks. It also happens in a completely different project with the code provided in my question which has nothing to do with my framework